# automatically send email if website not open

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

How to send automatically email to remind user before 1 month and this email will be send it every day and when the user put done it stop to send email and this script should work if the website is open or not in a browser
i have a due date for a paper i want before a month of this due date and for many days an email will be sending for the user and when the user update and put done this script stop to send an email
i have a db this an image for it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evgK2.png)

this is a picture i have start and end date with the duration between it

```
file name

user id

name enter by the user

date of uploaded file

and status this is will be 0 when he put done it will be 1
```

Comment: If you're using Linux, create a CRON script which does this.

Comment: So do I understand this right, your trying to send a email through PHP to every users email, which got the status db_duration = 0 right? If this is the case, where do you store the user email?

Answer (score 0):

Create a php that retrieve and send a mail to every users you want, and create a CRON task that execute this script once a day.

Everyday this will check every user and send the mail.

Comment: You need to do a query that fetch every users `WHERE`the difference between `your date` and `now()` is exaclty 1 month (unless you want a mail to be send everyday after one month). Then loop though every record and send the mail. At least try to do it, it's not a coding service, if you have more problems with a code we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: ok but this will work if the website it's not open in a browser?

Comment: Yes, if you setup a CRON task, this will execute your script, google CRON task to know more about them